# Undefined functions/methods - Intelephense(1013) - Laravel Homestead + VScode

Tags: php, laravel, visual-studio-code, virtual-machine, homestead

I have been working on learning laravel. I am using Homestead in conjunction with virtualbox - and my IDE is vscode. I have been getting the "problem lines" under inane things in my IDE... see below:
[image]

I cant figure out why something like "view" or "isNot" has those error lines. Everything works fine I am just wondering why the IDE is throwing intelephenser(1013) problems at me.

Here is the errors it is throwing:
[image]

Any ideas on getting rid of this would be appreciated! :D

Comment: I've found that Laravel doesn't play well with Intelephense, but using https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper helps with a lot of those errors.

Comment: also the method is `isNot` not `isNOt`

Comment: If the answer below worked for you, please set it as "the answer" to close of your question

Answer (score 5):

Laravel has global helper function and class aliases declared

You can use [barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper) to help your IDE recognize the helpers and aliases.

Follow [this guide](https://arunas.dev/laravel-intellisense/) if you struggle installing it.

basicly

```
$ composer require --dev barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper

$ php artisan ide-helper:generate
$ php artisan ide-helper:meta
$ php artisan ide-helper:models --nowrite
```

Comment: Did not seem to work for me. Not sure why.

Comment: You need to run `php artisan ide-helper:generate` at least once and reopen or better restart vscode.

Answer (score 2):

Add annotation to your variable like so:

```
/** @var \App\Models\User $user **/

$user = Auth::user();
```

It'd tell PHP intelephense that $user variable is not `Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User` but `\App\Models\User`.

Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69580333/11297747